# How can I transform a heterogenous array with lazy objects in it by creating values for each lazy object in F# (without reflection)

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation

How can I transform

```
let args : Object[] = [| lazy 7; "text"; lazy "lazytext" |]
```

into

```
[| 7; "text"; "lazytext" |]
```

This does not work:

```
let createvalue<'t> (v: Object) : Object =
    match v with
    | :? Lazy<'t> as x -> x.Value :> Object
    | x -> x

args |> Array.map createvalue
```

since createvalue<'t> is considered `createvalue<obj>` by the compiler such that the first pattern case does not match.

A non efficient solution is reflection:

```
let createvalue (v: Object) : Object =
    match v with
    | _ when v.GetType().Name = "Lazy`1" ->
        v.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, v, [||])
    | x -> x
```

but is there a clean straight F# way?

Comment: By making the array heterogeneous, you have erased the types of its elements. And since you insist on not knowing the types at compile time, the only other way to know them is at runtime, which is what reflection does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done cleanly with heterogenous `Lazy<'T>` elements, but since you're discarding the type info anyway, would you consider making them all `Lazy<obj>` to begin with instead? If so, the solution is clean:

```ml
let args : obj[] = [| lazy box 7; "text"; lazy box "lazytext" |]

let createvalue (v: obj) : obj =
    match v with
    | :? Lazy<obj> as x -> x.Value
    | x -> x
```

Comment: interesting idea. actually the simple api is a must. i rather stick with reflection, since logging is IO anyway, so reflection performance is not a deal. thx for this creative input.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.

Let's look at the types of the things you use:

```
let args : Object[] = [| lazy 7; "text"; lazy "lazytext" |]

let createValue<'t> (v: obj) : obj = ...

module Array =
    let inline map (mapping: 't -> 'u) (array:'t[]) = ...
```

So with all the generics, it may at first glance seem that what you're trying to do is correct. But if you look more closely then you see that
in your mapping function `createValue<'t>(obj)`, it's actually `obj` that's used in Array.map as the type `'t`. So if we fill in the types you get this (and also using that createValue returns an object):

```
let args : Object[] = [| lazy 7; "text"; lazy "lazytext" |]

let createValue<'t> (v: obj) : obj =
    match v with
    | :? Lazy<'t> as x -> x.Value :> Object
    | x -> x

module Array =
    let inline map (mapping: obj -> obj) (array:obj[]) = ...
```

So that shows that Array.map just takes a function that goes from `obj -> obj` in this case. But your `createValue<'otherT>(obj):obj` is still generic, so F# is going to infer the type of `'otherT` and because you don't do anything with the type, F# is going to infer 'obj'. So the function you're passing in will be analogous to:

```
let createValue (v: obj) : obj =
    match v with
    | :? Lazy<obj> as x -> x.Value :> Object
    | x -> x
```

You could also pass other concrete versions of createValue. E.g. if you use `args |> Array.map createvalue<int>` then it will work correctly for all int instances, but not for anything else.

If you know the types that the lazy can contain you could do something like:

```
let createvalue (v: obj) : obj =
    match v with
    | :? Lazy<int> as x -> x.Value :> obj
    | :? Lazy<string> as x -> x.Value :> obj
    | x -> x
```

But if you don't then I'm afraid you're stuck with reflection or change your approach like brianberns suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `createvalue` inline function and it should work.

Comment: no, that does not work. had thought already about that - that also becomes createvalue<obj>. Try yourself